# Как узнать размер файла? JS

Tags: javascript

У меня в HTML есть кнопка скачивания файла, я хочу что бы писался еще размер данного файла, конечно можно просто написать в HTML, но если файл изменится, заново менять размер? И решил спросить, можно ли с помощью JS узнать размер файла, или только с PHP?

Comment: В качестве самого кривого решения: добавьте размер в имя файла, если это допустимо

Comment: Через клиентский JS - никак, только если у вас бекэнд на node

Comment: получается только через PHP( Ладно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Правильное решение - получить размер файла в PHP на этапе формирования html страницы. Например, так:

```
<?php $sz = filesize("myfile.ext") / (1024 * 1024); printf("%3.2f Mb", $sz); ?>
```

Javascript для этого подходит плохо, потому что он выполняется на стороне клиента. Для того, чтобы сделать это в JS, нужно использовать AJAX, то есть направить запрос на сервер, получить ответ с размером файла, и вставить его на страницу. По сравнению с одной строчкой PHP работы больше минимум на порядок.

Answer (score 1):

Можно при помощи AJAX запроса попробоать:

```
var url = "path-to-your-file.pdf";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, false);
req.send();
console.log(req.getResponseHeader('content-length'));
```

P.S. ответ взят с https://qna.habr.com/q/513753